# android ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree() Intent always opens the previous use last folder

Tags: android, activityresultcontracts

I am working on a android app which I want the user to be able to export the user entered data without the need for third party apps or cloud storage.  I think that the user should be able to export the data to a folder on the device that can later be used to import into the application or whatever else the user wants to do with it without having to dig into the app specific location.  To do this I thought that the OpenDocumentTree would be the best way to do it.  And other than the issue (below) it works just fine (using DocumentFile to create folders and files).  I searched for a solution but could not find anything so...

in module gradle
android {
compileSdkVersion 33

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.inventory"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

The issue:

When launching ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree(), the file picker never uses the "start at" Uri.  It always opens the file picker starting in the folder of the last used launch.  And the "Use This Folder" Button is not displayed and because the app creates a folder to use for app data export, the user has to navigate up before the "Use This Folder" Button is displayed. I think this might be confusing for some users. I have tried Uri.fromFile(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS));
and Uri.parse("content://com.android.providers.media.documents"); but these are either invalid or just ignored.  I don't care if it starts in the Documents folder or some other folder as long the file picker starts at the requested Uri every time and displays the Use this Folder Button or informs the user that the folder is not usable and prompts to create a folder.  I'm hoping that I am overlooking something simple as I am still learning my way around the android operating system.

I tried on a virtual device api 30 and samsung galaxy note 8 api 27
tried using
Uri.fromFile(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS));
and
Uri.parse("content://com.android.providers.media.documents");

Expecting the file picker to start in the DOCUMENTS folder (or some other folder) consistently.

Code snippet:

```
public class ExportInventoryFragment extends Fragment
{
    ContentResolver resolver;

    FragmentExportInventoryBinding binding;
    Uri exportFileUri;

    private DocumentFile selectedExportFolder;

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        binding.exportInventoryStartButton.setEnabled(false);

        binding.exportInventorySearchButton.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            binding.exportInventorySelectedFolderText.setText("");
            binding.exportInventoryStartButton.setEnabled(false);
           selectInventoryExportFolder.launch(Uri.fromFile(requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)));
        });

        binding.exportInventoryStartButton.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            if (selectedExportFolder != null) {
                binding.exportInventoryStartButton.setEnabled(false);
                exportInventory();
            }
        });
    }


    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> selectInventoryExportFolder = this.registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree(), result -> {
                try {
                    if (result != null) {
                        DocumentFile docFolder = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(requireContext(), result);
                        if (docFolder == null) {
                            Snackbar.make(requireView(), "Nothing selected...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        if (!docFolder.isDirectory()) {
                            Snackbar.make(requireView(), "Selected is Not a Folder", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        if (!docFolder.canWrite()) {
                            Snackbar.make(requireView(), "Unable to Write Selected Folder Files", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }


                        binding.exportInventorySelectedFolderText.setText(
                                String.format("%s %s",
                                        getString(R.string.text_selected_folder),
                                        selectedExportFolder.getName()));

                        selectedExportFolder = docFolder;

                        // This button allows the user to continue
                        binding.exportInventoryStartButton.setEnabled(true);
                    } else {
                        Snackbar.make(requireView(), "Nothing selected...", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception x) {
                    Log.e("SelectImageFolder Launcher", x.getMessage(), x);
                    Snackbar.make(requireView(), Objects.requireNonNull(x.getMessage()), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: The only valid initial Uris are Uris returned by previous calls to `OpenDocumentTree` (e.g., something you'd use if you want the user to reselect what folder they want to export to). What makes you think a File Uri or a hard coded Uri would do anything?

Comment: When using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, your app gains access only to the files in the directory that the user selects. You don't have access to other apps' files that reside outside this user-selected directory. This user-controlled access allows users to choose exactly what content they're comfortable sharing with your app.

Optionally, you can specify the URI of the directory that the file picker should display when it first loads by using the EXTRA_INITIAL_URI intent extra.

Comment: From https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files

Comment: Yeah, if only there was some documentation on what a tree uri is.

Comment: Open Document Tree returns tree Uris, hence the name. What did you think it returned?

Comment: I thought that it returned a uri.  Sorry for the bother, I'll figure it out.